# R LME4 mixed models with nesting and nesting-interactions

Tags: r, nested, lme4, mixed-models

I'm not sure how to write the model in lmer for a mixed model with nesting and random nested interactions. My response variable in this example is Consumer rated Sweet taste, which is on a continuous scale.

My model with fixed effects(all discrete variables), 3 way-interactions thereof and one random effect, Subject, looks like this:

```
apple.st.m1 <- lmer(Sweet_taste ~   
           (Gender + Agegroup + Frequencygroup + Aroma + Sugar )^3 +
           (1|Subject)
         ,data=apple.data)
```

Moreover, in the random effects both Gender, Agegroup and Frequencygroup should all be nested in ID. It is important that these are not nested within each out but
individually nested within ID.
As I understand this is done the following way:

```
a.st.m <- lmer(Sweet_taste ~   
           (Gender + Agegroup + Frequencygroup + Aroma + Sugar )^3 +
           (1|Subject/Gender) + (1|Subject/Agegroup) + (1|Subject/Frequencygroup),
           data=apple.data)
```

However, I also want to put in two random interactions with Subject, like this:

```
(1|Subject:Aroma) + (1|Subject:Sugar)
```

So while Gender, Agegroup and Frequencygroup are nested within Subject, I also want that Subject has one interaction with Aroma and another with Sugar.

How is this done correctly?

Fore more insight in my data, here is a data.frame screenshot:
[apple.data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bm3qU.jpg)

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean by "Subject has one interaction with Aroma and another with Sugar". If you mean that each subject may have different slopes for Aroma and Sugar then you should include random slopes, e.g. `(Aroma | Subject)`.